# Get value from DOM in iframe (not parent page)

Tags: javascript, dom

I know the subject might be a bit confusing, but in my searching i found LOTS of questions about getting value from parent page when inside iframe. This is not what i want to achive.

I have 2 html pages and a js file. This is how they look:

outer.html:

```
...
<body>
<iframe src="./inner.html"></iframe>
</body>
....
```

inner.html

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var somevar = { id:302 };
        (function() { 
var ml = document.createElement('script'); 
ml.type = 'text/javascript'; 
ml.async = true; 
ml.src = './some.js'; 
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
s.parentNode.insertBefore(ml, s);
}) ();
        </script> 
    </head>
```

some.js:

```
console.log(parent.somevar);
```

What im expecting is that code in some.js would output the "somevar" object, but it outputs 'undefined'. If i run the inner.html directly (not through iframe element) then it outputs the object fine.

If i do

```
console.log(parent);
```

I get the DOM of the parent window (outer.html).

So my question is - how do i get the DOM of inner.html from the some.js file (or other script tags in the inner.html)

BR/Sune

Comment: `$("iframe #someEleID")` ??? of course that requires jQuery, but is way easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log(somevar)`?

Comment: Heh - this actually seems to work. Now im just wondering why the script had "parent.somevar" in the first place? Wierd